# Generating svg using js code, it keeps returning the same result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, parameters

Sorry, I didn't really know how to decide the title properly. Let me explain what I am experiencing.

So I am trying to generate some svg elements and add them into my div. Here's my code:

```
const drawInfographics = (data) => {
  console.log(data);

  const generateSymbol = (width) => {
    return `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="unown" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 400 334">
       <path d="M195.083 13.357 C 155.599 14.240,116.551 28.209,85.250 52.650 L 82.917 54.472 77.083 48.676 C 70.927 42.559,69.949 41.744,67.264 40.490 C 51.251 33.013,34.125 48.036,39.513 64.833 C 40.788 68.809,41.805 70.168,48.676 77.083 L 54.472 82.917 52.650 85.250 C 6.781 143.993,0.434 225.132,36.600 290.417 C 40.050 296.646,42.329 299.118,46.565 301.230 C 60.057 307.955,75.667 298.355,75.667 283.333 C 75.667 279.026,74.959 276.681,72.106 271.534 C 26.856 189.889,67.396 88.127,156.333 60.109 C 163.475 57.859,176.941 54.833,179.813 54.833 C 179.950 54.833,180.000 58.461,180.000 68.250 C 180.000 81.235,179.990 81.667,179.689 81.667 C 179.518 81.667,178.224 81.896,176.814 82.177 C 113.956 94.696,72.109 153.756,81.169 217.167 C 90.527 282.662,151.496 328.240,217.167 318.832 C 269.767 311.296,311.231 269.851,318.819 217.225 C 320.981 202.230,320.222 186.196,316.658 171.566 C 305.469 125.630,267.906 90.156,221.708 81.895 L 220.000 81.589 220.000 68.211 C 220.000 57.620,220.043 54.833,220.208 54.834 C 222.179 54.838,233.093 57.090,238.833 58.677 C 313.324 79.273,358.928 153.634,343.565 229.449 C 340.627 243.950,335.172 258.536,327.667 271.963 C 325.068 276.612,324.333 279.118,324.333 283.333 C 324.333 297.873,339.056 307.498,352.444 301.710 C 356.686 299.876,359.772 296.902,362.541 291.978 C 399.622 226.035,393.632 144.525,347.350 85.250 L 345.528 82.917 351.324 77.083 C 358.121 70.243,359.085 68.974,360.382 65.167 C 366.015 48.633,349.387 33.280,333.353 40.211 C 330.251 41.553,329.555 42.116,323.083 48.526 L 317.083 54.469 314.887 52.753 C 283.743 28.423,244.001 14.094,205.750 13.405 C 203.275 13.360,200.950 13.307,200.583 13.286 C 200.217 13.265,197.742 13.297,195.083 13.357 M207.083 120.435 C 244.223 123.654,274.515 152.755,279.234 189.750 C 285.334 237.565,248.150 279.845,200.000 279.845 C 148.966 279.845,110.950 232.476,122.014 182.674 C 130.707 143.546,167.038 116.965,207.083 120.435 M195.849 180.344 C 181.455 183.447,175.155 200.402,184.024 212.171 C 192.270 223.115,209.134 222.537,216.777 211.049 C 220.423 205.570,221.049 198.071,218.377 191.890 C 214.702 183.388,204.939 178.384,195.849 180.344" />
       <path d="M203.058 186.903 C 193.647 189.186,195.319 203.333,205.000 203.333 C 209.498 203.333,213.333 199.498,213.333 195.000 C 213.333 189.703,208.198 185.656,203.058 186.903" fill="#ffffff" />
    </symbol>
 
    <g clip-path="url(#cutout)">
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="10" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="60" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="110" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="160" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="210" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="360" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="410" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="460" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="510" y="5" />
       <use xlink:href="#unown" x="560" y="5" />
    </g>
 
    <defs>
       <clipPath id="cutout">
          <rect x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="${width}%" />
       </clipPath>
    </defs>
 </svg>
    `;
  };

  document.getElementById("infog-day-one").innerHTML += generateSymbol(
    data[0]
  );

  document.getElementById("infog-day-two").innerHTML += generateSymbol(
    data[1]
  );
};
```

As you can see I am passing "data" as a parameter and it is an array of numbers. If the value is 40, then it will clip the svg for 40% (look at the defs tag inside)

And all values of data array is different. So what I am experiencing is, at the end of the code, document.getElementById, as you can see they are trying to use different value (index) of the data array. But they are generating exactly the same svg.

So if the data array is [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70] then what I wanted is the first div with id "infog-day-one" clips 20% of the image, and the div with id "infog-day-two" clips 30%, and so on.

But everything just clips 20%. I have tried everything I can do. Changing div's id and etc. Nothing works.

Can anyone please help? I am going crazy now.

Comment: So you are sure it is passing in a different width? `const generateSymbol = (width) => { console.log('width', width); ....`

Comment: Yeah I tried console.log and it is all different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing the `clipPath` from its `id`. No matter how you create it, there can only be one definition per `id` in an html document. When you add the second `svg` (data[1]), there are two `#cutout` ids, and the behavior is not defined. You might try something like `<clipPath id="cutout-${width}%">`, and referencing it like that in each `svg`. In that case, you would have to make sure that you are not creating two svgs with the same `width` (it would work, but it would not be correct).

Comment: WOW. Thank you so much. I've been struggling for 5 hours now and this solved the problem. Thank you so much again